# For loop with specific function

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I have a small problem with a program I am working on.

My program executes a function on an array.  The function only can execute the commands on the first 16 elements of the array.

I now want to make a loop so that the function can work on more than 16 elements of the array.  Here's my thought, but it ended up in an infinite loop:

```
int l = 0;
for (int i=0; i<=size; i+16)
{
    for (int j=0; j<=16;j++)
    {
        FUNCTION(INARRAY; OUTARRAY);
    }
}
```

Next problem is that the function will only walk through 16 Elements of the array and ignore the rest.

What is the best way to make it walk through the next 16 elements and save it in the outbuffer as the following elements?

As I adapt the solution it still does only process through the first 16 elements and then doesn't continue with the next 16.

Comment: how will you decide how many elements are checked?

Comment: the function itself has a limit of 16 elements

Comment: Please do not edit the post to ask a completely unrelated question, it gets very confusing for the reader, especially as the current answer only applies to the previous question. Edit the post when you want to add more information and details about the _same_ question, otherwise please start up a new question as a separate post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured this one out some time ago
here's how it worked for me

```
for (uint64_t i=0; i<size; i+=16)
{aes_encrypt(tfm, &tempbuffer[i], &inbuffer[i]);}
```

this does the following
calling aes_encrypt will encrypt the first 16 bytes of data in the array,
the for loop then jumps to the 16th entry and performs the encryption again

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
i + 16
```

does nothing to change the value of `i`, so that loop never terminates. That expression just computes the value of `i + 16`, but the result is thrown away.

To change the value of a variable, use assignment (`=`) operator, like `i = i + 16` or `i += 16`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you are looking for. You would have to implent it and check it out. Be warned though that this worked if your arrays size is a multiple of 16, otherwise there will be remaining elements paired with already processed elements.

```
int count16 = 0;
var tempAr[16];
for (int i=0; i<numOfArraysToGoThrough; i++)
{    
    tempAr[count16]=numOfArrayToGoThrough[i];
    if ( count16 == 15)
    {
    FUNCTION (tempAr, OUTARRAY);
    count16=0;
    }
    else
    count16+=1;

}
```

Comment: FUNCTION is AES Encrypt / Decrypt, the function only en/decrypts a 128bit block and then finished, I would like to write a loop so that i can en/decrypt an array with more than 16 elements

Comment: So do you want to loop through multiple arrays, or just loop through an array with more than 16 elements? or both?

Comment: loop through array1 and write result into array2, just one array to loop through

Comment: But you are saying that the function can only handle an array with 16 elements? Does your function take an array as an argument or just a value?

Comment: yes it is limited to a 128bit block size and i want to loop through the array so that it will en/decrypt the next block, which is equal to 16 elements of the array

Comment: takes the array as an argument. i allocate an array, write some random data in it, for example 32 times, and then pass it as the inbuffer to the encrypt function, together with the outbuffer

Comment: I updated my answer, but why not divide your data up into arrays of size 16? That is basically what I did in my answer.

Comment: the idea of dividing the array is good for small arrays. but at the end of the programm i would like to have large arrays of several hundrets of MB, and dividing them every 16 elements would not be very efficient

Comment: How else can you get around it if the function only takes arrays of size 16? Wouldn't you need to rewrite that function?

Comment: rewriting the encrypt/decrypt function unfortunately is not an option. I am not allowed to change the functin itself. 
isnt there any other way?